# Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' error

Tags: c#

> CS0029 Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'string' to 'Fatura_uygulaması.BLL.userBLL'

```
class categoriesBLL // my bll file
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string title { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }

        public DateTime added_date { get; set; }

        public int added_by { get; set; }
    }




userBLL usr = dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser); // I get the error on this line
```

Comment: what is `userBLL` ?

Comment: Well, `dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser)` returns `string` (e.g. `"12345"`) and having this `string` the compiler *can't create* a corresponding `usr` which is of type `userBLL`. You, probably, have to call a *constructor* like `userBLL usr = new userBLL(dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser));`

Comment: You show a "categoriesBLL" class, but your problem line uses a "userBLL" class. Can you show that instead (as an [edit] to your question)? And also show the signature (type of parameters and return type) of that dal.GetIDFromUsername

Answer (score 0):

```
dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser)
```

is returning you a string which you are storing it in UserBLL type of Object.

either you should change the datatype of usr to string or you can change the return type of 'GetIDFromUsername' method from string to UserBLL

try Doing this -->

```
string usr = dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser).toString();
```

Comment: thank you. but when i try this ,i am getting a new error. Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: return type of dal.GetIDFromUsername(loggedUser) methos is string?? is it correct??? and you have changed the datatype of usr to string??

Comment: Hey try adding 'ToString()' ater the method call.

Comment: If `dal.GetIDFromUsername` already returns a `string`, then adding a `.ToString()` does nothing useful.

Comment: i just suggested him to cope up with that exception.